# Tried to hqve time duration fileds in amchartd

Tags: amcharts

In amchart libraray handle time duration enter by user must handle in html 
Showing tine duration is possible but showing as time duration user can select dqte from to seem qmstock  is not possible. 8 hqve a series chart in amchart and i want tine filed in htmtime dynamic loaded
Pararyner for shown time start and end
dataLoader: { url: "/path/to/endpoint", complete: function(chart) { chart.addTitle( "Data from " + chart.dataProvider[0][chart.categoryField] + " to " + chart.dataProvider[chart.dataProvider.length - 1][ chart.categoryField ], 16, "#444444", 1, true ); } },

Comment: Would it be possible ot post your setup as a fiddle/plunker/codepen? It's hard to tell what problem you're having and what the desired result is.

Comment: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/72e0f2f2791365912692b5f5903cf266?editors=0010

Comment: That's the codepen *I* created last time for your previous question. You need to provide a demo/[MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that relates to *your* current setup and reproduces your current problem. Fork/copy the code from that codepen into your own and modify it.